# Does Document AI not detect the shopping receipt?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I can successfully extract the details of the shopping receipt (products, store name, etc.) with the expense parser in Document AI. I wrote the store name and product name in handwriting on normal paper and uploaded it, but it still took out the information. Does Document AI not understand if this is a shopping receipt?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @codinges can you please upload/attach a screenshot of the receipt to your question? It will be easier for us (the community) to help you if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai) recognizes that it is a shopping receipt. Document AI just extracts the data of the receipt that is not handwritten.
If you want to upload a [handwritten](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting#handwriting_detection_with_optical_character_recognition_ocr) receipt, you need to upload an image, PDF or TIFF files, which are the formats in which the OCR recognizes handwriting text.

> Document AI is a document understanding solution that takes
> unstructured data (documents, forms, etc.) and makes the data easier
> to understand, analyze, and consume by providing structure through
> content classification, entity extraction, advanced searching, and
> more.

An option could be to use [AutoML Vision Object Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs) to convert sections of images into text documents.

Answer (score 0):

Document AI OCR can support [handwriting](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages#handwriting-scripts) in any [supported file format](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/file-types).

The [Expense Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_expense-parser) is a specialized processor trained for parsing receipts, however it may not perform as expected for non-printed receipts (since most receipts are printed in similar formats).

I recommend reviewing over the documentation for [handling the processing response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#fields_and_normalized_values) for specialized processors.

You can also try out the [Specialized Processors codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-specialized-processors-python) which demonstrates how to extract entities for any specialized processor.

The documentation also contains a [Sample Receipt PDF and full output from the Expense Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/output#processor_expense-parser).